# Implementing Oracle Database Triggers

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers

Below is the code snippet which I need to improve.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE T_CHANGE AFTER ---Trigger Created for After insert/update option
INSERT OR 
UPDATE OF QTY ON ABC BEGIN 
IF INSERTING THEN 
UPDATE XYZ D SET FLAG_CHG = 1 
WHERE EXISTS 
(
SELECT 1 FROM XYZ D WHERE 
:NEW.PRODUCT = D.PRODUCT AND 
:NEW.LOCATION = D.LOCATION 
);

IF UPDATING THEN 
UPDATE XYZ D SET FLAG_CHG = 1 
WHERE EXISTS 
(
SELECT 1 FROM XYZ D WHERE 
:OLD.PRODUCT = D.PRODUCT AND 
:OLD.LOCATION = D.LOCATION `enter code here`
);

END IF 
END T_CHANGE;

The two mentioned tables are as follow:

CREATE TABLE XYZ (
PRODUCT VARCHAR2(50),
LOCATION VArchar2(50),
FLAG_CHG BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0,
CONSTRAINT XYZ_PK PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCT,LOCATION)
)

CREATE TABLE ABC (
PRODUCT VARCHAR2(50),
LOCATION VArchar2(50),
QTY NUMBER,
CONSTRAINT ABC_PK PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCT,LOCATION)
)
```

What are you trying to achieve ?

1)If the QTY in ABC is updated or inserted the FLAG_CHG in XYZ should be updated to 1.

I have few queries on this

```
1.) Will the above code work? :P
2.) If works, will it have performance issues ?
3.) How can I enhance this code to improve the performance ?
4.) Please advice a better approach ,if any,to fulfill the requirement?
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: For one thing, you don't need the subqueries in your UPDATE statements - just put the filters directly in the WHERE clause. Otherwise your updates will apply to ALL the records in the table. Also, you're missing an END IF after the first update statement.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because SQL won't recognize what you are going to do there, I guess.

The better approch for it is to create some unique fields in your table, and then do query `INSERT` .... `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` ...

Reference

[UPDATE on DUPLICATE KEY ORACLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Creating trigger is a part of requirement. I do not need to insert any values  but  I only want to update the flag in XYZ if the QTY col in ABC is updated or a new row is inserted for the (Product,Location) combination existing in XYZ.

Comment: You need to use your logic with what has been provided by the sql query then, for example with `update on duplicate key' query.